# UITableView transform property not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have `UITableView` in my app,

I am using transform property of `UITableView`

When i write this line in `iOS 7`

`tblFilter.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);`

it works properly but when i run same project in `iOS 8` it doesn't work it's strange error :(

```
How can i solve this ??
```

**please help and thanks in advance.**

Comment: What **is** the error?

Comment: there is no error but table doesn't rotate in iOS 8

Comment: Where do you set the transform?

Answer (score 2):

You should try this in `viewWillAppear`, UI related things are ready to be displayed in this event so it will work.

Comment: Doesn't work in `viewWillAppear` i don't think this to be an issue because the same thing works in `iOS 7` and not in 8

Comment: Is this the UITableView only or transform doesn't work with any UIView ?

Comment: I tried to transform `UILabel` in `ViewDidLoad` it works.. but same code doesn't work with `UITableView` :(

Comment: Have you tried to move UITableView inside a UIView and transform that UIView ?

Comment: `tblFilter.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);` when i write this in `ViewDidApper` it rotates but scroll inside tableview is still vertical, i want that to be horizontal possible ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use scale, not rotation, so that the scroll bar still works:

```
 tblFilter.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)
```

Comment: Tried your code table is horizontal but scroll inside table is still vertical. i also want scroll horizontal possible ?

Comment: I suggest you use a `UICollectionView` if you want a horizontally scrolling list. You can try rotating the `UITableView` but your code for doing that was correct and if it doesn't work...