# UIView transform inside a UITableViewCell does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have this up arrow button inside a UITableViewCell that should rotate 180 degrees when clicked or when the method gets called somewhere else. This actually works when you click the button and update the sender.transform.

```
@IBAction func rotate(sender: UIButton) {

if (top)
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((360.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
    })

}
else
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
    })

}
```

}

If I change the code so that I reference the button instead from the UITableViewCell to something like this, this does not work. The button does not rotate.

```
IBAction func rotate(sender: UIButton) {

let detailCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! DetailCell

if (top)
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        detailCell.arrowButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((360.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
    })

}
else
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        detailCell.arrowButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
    })

}
```

}

Basically, I want to be able to rotate the button from the UITableViewCell in another method that does not involve clicking the button, so I need to be able to reference the button from the UITableViewCell and rotate it.  What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of different choices.

If you create a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` then you can add an outlet to you button to the cell. Ask the table view for the cell, cast it to to your custom class, and then use the outlet to the button (`myCustomCell.button`).

The other option is to add a unique tag to the button, and then use `cell.contentView.viewWithTag(tagNumber)`. Then cast the result from UIView to UIButton.

Using a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` and an outlet is cleaner and less fragile, but more work to set up.

Comment: I may not have specified it but the arrowButton is an IBOutlet from my custom UITableViewCell.  I am expecting that the sender and detailCell.arrowButton are the same and should both rotate.  Only the sender from the IBAction rotates and that's only available if the action is coming from a click.  If I click, and instead of the sender I specifically reference the arrowButton outlet from the cell, it does nothing.

Comment: You probably have a broken outlet. Log arrowButton. I bet it's nil.

Comment: I do not think it is nil though I did not log it.  When I put it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, it does not do animation but it rotates it 180 but then I can't get it to rotate again even if I try to reloadData and rotate it based on some flag.

Comment: Also, it sounds similar to what this user has issue with.  I am in iOS 8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135655/uitableview-transform-property-not-working-in-ios-8

Comment: Ok, I printed it out and it looks like they have different addresses.  In fact, the sender has the same address all the time while the address for the arrowButton referenced from the cell changes, it's different every time.  I guess the question is how do I get that same exact button as that sender?  Same thing with the cell, the address is different every time.  I am expecting the cellForRowAtIndexPath for a section and row that's already visible will return the same address.

Answer (score 0):

At least, Duncan got me in the right track by suggesting to do print out.  Anyway, once I realized the sender and the arrowButton from the cell have different addresses and it at least rotates once in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, I decided to save that first arrowButton object somewhere else, and then uses that for the transform.  Something like this:

```
var saveArrowButton: UIButton?
```

At the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method:

```
 if (saveArrowButton == nil)
 {
     saveArrowButton = detailCell.arrowButton
  }
```

And in the rotate method:  I am referencing saveArrowButton!.transform.  That seems to work so far.